# Magento configurable downloadable product error in My Downloadable Products page

Tags: php, magento

On a fresh install of Magento, I have a configurable product with an associated downloadable product applied.
After purchasing this product, in the My Downloadable Products page the following error appears:

> Book TEST Product Name - ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   __() on a non-object in /path/to/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/customer/products/list.phtml
>   on line 60

How was it resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello your line no 60 should look like this :

```
<td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getPurchased()->getProductName()) ?> - <a href="<?php echo $this->getDownloadUrl($_item) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('downloadable')->__('Start Download') ?>" <?php echo $this->getIsOpenInNewWindow()?'onclick="this.target=\'_blank\'"':''; ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getLinkTitle()); ?></a></td>
```

you can change this to this :

```
<td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getPurchased()->getProductName()) ?> - <a href="<?php echo $this->getDownloadUrl($_item) ?>" title="" <?php echo $this->getIsOpenInNewWindow()?'onclick="this.target=\'_blank\'"':''; ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getLinkTitle()); ?></a></td>
```

remove the this `<?php echo Mage::helper('downloadable')->__('Start Download') ?>` and check